# How to install a letsencrypt cert with nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I've used [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to install an SSL cert for the latest nginx on ubuntu.
The setup is fine and works great with the exception of:

[image]

I don't know enough about SSL to know what's going on but I have a suspicion:
I installed the SSL cert for Apache a while back and just now moved to Nginx for it's http/2 support. As the nginx plugin is not stable yet I had to install the cert myself and this is what I did:

In my nginx config (`/etc/nginx/conf/default.conf`) I added:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  [domain];
    return 301   https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 http2;
    listen       [::]:443 http2;
    server_name  [domain];

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domain]/privkey.pem;
}
```

Is it possible that this breaks the chain somehow? What is the proper way here?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) For strong Diffie-Hellman and avoid Logjam attacks see [this great manual](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html).

You need extend your nginx config with these directives (after you will generate dhparams.pem file):

```
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
```

2) For correct certificate chain use fullchain.pem, not cert.pem, see [this great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) for details.

And you will get A grade :)

3) and as bonus try this great service:

["Generate Mozilla Security Recommended Web Server Configuration Files"](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/).

Comment: For the generator what are the options? `Intermediate` and `HSTS` enabled?

Comment: Now working on generating the `dhparams.pem`... Thanks for the help good sir!